# Can't pass argument to `stat_function()` in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to evaluate `pi` using [Nilakantha's infinite series](http://www.wikihow.com/Calculate-Pi)
π = 3 + 4/(2*3*4) - 4/(4*5*6) + 4/(6*7*8) - 4/(8*9*10) + 4/(10*11*12) - 4/(12*13*14) ....    and can't make `stat_function` work.
I wrote the following function:

```
  est.pi <- function(n){
  pi <- 3
  for (i in 1:n) {
    den <- (2*i)*(2*i+1)*(2*i+2)
    if (i %% 2 == 0) {
      pi <- pi - 4/den}
    else {
      pi <- pi + 4/den}
  }
  return(pi)
  }
```

which works well:

```
> options(digits = 10)
> est.pi(10000)
[1] 3.141592654
```

but when I try to plot it in ggplot2, `stat_function()` only evaluates the first argument:

```
n <- 10
s.x <- scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1,10))  
s.y <- scale_y_continuous(limits=c(3.13,3.17), breaks=seq(3.13, 3.17, 0.01))
ggplot(data.frame(x = 1:n), aes(x)) + stat_function(fun = est.pi) + s.x + s.y
```

[image]

However, if I manually create a data frame, it behaves as expected and converges nicely around 3.14159:

```
pi. <- data.frame(x = 1:n)
pi. <- within (pi., pi.est <- sapply (x, est.pi))
ggplot(pi., aes(x=x, y=pi.est)) + geom_line() + s.x + s.y
```

[image]

How could I make `stat_function` evaluate the `x` vector on the fly? Thanks.

Comment: Agree, this question is a duplicate.

Comment: Look at https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Vectorize.html and apply to your function